# Retrieve specific hash block from Hiera and pass to define

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a `define` function and i *was* invoking it from site manifest as and when required with different parameters. The parameter details were also present in site manifest only. I am *now* trying to use Hiera to store these parameter details.

```
[tom@pe-server] cat role_dll.pp
define sql::role_ddl (
    $role_ddl_params
) {
    $role_ddl_sql = $role_ddl_params[role_ddl_sql]
    $user = $role_ddl_params[user]
    $db = $role_ddl_params[db]

    ...code to consume above variables...
}


[tom@pe-server] cat my_node.yaml
role_ddl_params:
    userA:
        role_ddl_sql: 'f:/db/ddl.sql',
        user: 'my_domain\\userA',
        db: 'test_db',
    userB:
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Now i don't want to iterate through the complete hash. Rather, i would like to invoke a specific block from the above hash. Say for example, hash block corresponding only to userA. I'm not sure how to do that in the node block shown below:

```
[tom@pe-server] cat site.pp
node 'my_node' {
    sql::role_ddl { 'Granting ddl access to userA':
        role_ddl_params => hiera('role_ddl_params')
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Based on the suggestion in comment, i tried but i'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while eval
uating a Function Call, undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:10
0:22 on node my_node.abc.com","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR","stacktrace":["Warning: The 'stacktrace' property is deprecated and will be
removed in a future version of Puppet. For security reasons, stacktraces are not returned with Puppet HTTP Error responses."]}
```

I came across this [link](https://ask.puppet.com/question/15737/hiera-key-for-nested-yaml-hash/) and i tried the following way but still failing with above error:

```
node 'my_node' {
    $ddl_params = hiera('role_ddl_params')

    sql::role_ddl { 'Granting ddl access to userA':
        role_ddl_params => $ddl_params['userA']
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to just do a simple direct kv lookup. In other words, `hiera('role_ddl_params')['userA']` should work, as I have done a Hiera lookup followed immediately by a kv lookup before and it worked as expected.

Comment: @MattSchuchard: Please check UPDATE section above.

Comment: That could mean various issues with your lookup, such as a typo in the key in your data or the lookup, or all kinds of other mistakes with the lookup. Take a good luck at your code and data to see where the issue may be.

Comment: You were right @Matt. I was using `role_ddl_params` instead of `sql::role_ddl::role_ddl_params` in my YAML file. :( Thanks a lot for the help. Can you kindly post your suggestion as an answer so that this post gets closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a direct key-value access on the hash lookup from your hieradata to access the nested hash for a specific user.

For example, you can do it immediately after the `hiera` function lookup:

```
node 'my_node' {
    $ddl_params = hiera('role_ddl_params')['userA']

    sql::role_ddl { 'Granting ddl access to userA':
        role_ddl_params => $ddl_params
    }
}
```

or on a variable that is storing the result of the lookup:

```
node 'my_node' {
    $ddl_params = hiera('role_ddl_params')

    sql::role_ddl { 'Granting ddl access to userA':
        role_ddl_params => $ddl_params['userA']
    }
}
```

You can also completely inline this, although this might detract from code expressiveness:

```
node 'my_node' {
    sql::role_ddl { 'Granting ddl access to userA':
        role_ddl_params => hiera('role_ddl_params')['userA']
    }
}
```

On a related side note, seeing the following error thrown:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while eval
>   uating a Function Call, undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

from a `hiera` function lookup indicates you either performed a lookup on a `nil` key, or a key with a `nil` value. Both of those usually point to some kind of typo in the key used in the data or lookup, and more uncommonly to a lookup performed at the wrong priority in the hierarchy, data missing in the hieradata, or an actual `nil` value for a key in the hieradata.